# interface implementation changes pointcut interpretation

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I want to select all methods annotated with @RequestMapping in classes annotated with @Controller.

The following pointcut definition works fine ... in some cases:

```
@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller)
    and
@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)
```

The problem is, that as soon as the @Controller-annotated class implements some interface, the pointcut is not applicable any more and the methods do not get intercepted. This even happens, when I just implement java.io.Serializable.

This for example does not work, but it works as soon as I remove the "*implements Serializable*":

```
@Controller
public class TestController extends BaseController implements Serializable {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String testAuth1(final Model model) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Spring XML config:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="handlerMethods"
        expression="@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller) and @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)" />
    <aop:aspect ref="handlerAdvice">
        <aop:before method="interceptionMethod" pointcut-ref="handlerMethods" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Any ideas about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `BaseController` implementing any interface?

Seems like you are creating a cglib proxy until you add the interface implementation  so the more simple try to solve it is adding `proxy-target-class = "true"` to `<aop:config>` :

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
...
</aop:config>
```

If you want to use JDK proxies, you need to move annotations to a interface or spring mvc will not see thems.

Comment: Didn't know there was a way to enforce CGLIB. Thanks!